# Alert only "message" portion of {"success":"false","message":"Credit card number is invalid. "}

Tags: php, ajax, json

As you can see from the title I want to have an alert popup show "Credit card number is invalid."

I'm currently using alert(data.responseText); but that displays "Credit card number cannot be updated to an unsupported card type when it is associated to subscriptions.
Credit card type is not accepted by this merchant account.
Credit card number is invalid.
{"success":"false","message":"Credit card number is invalid."}"

Is there any way to just display the "Credit card number is invalid" portion.

If I use alert(data.Message)); gives "undefined" and alert(data); gives "[object Object]".

Thank you for your help.

```
var data = {
                "action": "checkout"
            };
            data = $('#checkout_form').serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "inc/placeorder.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data["success"] == 'true'){
                        $("#placeorder").attr("disabled",false);
                        $(".payment_loader").fadeOut("slow").hide();
            $('#checkout_form').trigger("reset");
                        window.location = "order_success.php"; 

                    }
                    if(data["success"] == 'false'){
                        $("#placeorder").attr("disabled",true);
                        $(".payment_loader").fadeOut("slow").hide();
                       $('#subscribe_response').html(data['message']);
                      alert(data.responseText);

                    }
                },
                error: function(data, status){
                    alert(data);

                    console.log("error", data.responseText);
                    console.log("error", status.responseText);

}
            });                         
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
```

EDIT

this is the error that is being thrown.

```
} else {

    foreach ($result->errors->deepAll() as $error) {

        $errorFound = $error->message . "<br />";

        echo $errorFound;


    }

    $response = array("success" => "false", "message" => $errorFound);

    return $response;

    exit;

}
```

Comment: `alert(data.message);` ?

Comment: What about the `data['message']` you have in the line *just* before your alert?

Comment: if you mean alert(data['message'];

Answer (score 0):

Actually you set response type "json" in you ajax request, but you are not getting the response in "json".Use json_encode function in you php script for json response return

```
return json_encode(response);
```

Then alert

```
alert(data.message);
```